# z-index to a background? CSS

Tags: html, css, z-index

I have couple of list items with specified height and width with a background which has borders with middle portions being transparent.
each li contains an image.

```
<ul id="reel">
    <li><img src="movie-image"></li>
    <li><img src="movie-image"></li>
    <li><img src="movie-image"></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
#reel { width:960px; height:270px;}
#reel li { width:320px; height:327px; z-index:100; }
#reel li img { z-index:98; }
```

I want the background of the li to appear over the image. z-index, didn't do the trick for me.
any suggestion?

Comment: can you please show us ur CSS code

Comment: Yes, seeing the CSS would help, but off the top of my head have you tried setting the z-index of the <img> to be lower than that of the <li>?  Without seeing your CSS I can't tell where you tried using z-index previously.

Comment: i posted the css above.. z-index of the img is lower than that of li.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think that in order to make use of z-index you have to explicitly give the element a position attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a pseudo element.  This presumes the image is 100px by 100px

```
li {               
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
}

li:after {
    content:"";
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:#000;
    display:inline-block;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I suggest making the li image with a position absolute and a value of x and y in minus 100 or more as you need it to keep the li image away so that the background image shows up. Something like below:

```
#reel li { width:320px; height:327px; z-index:100; }
#reel li img { position:absolute; left: -100px; top: -100px; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Nicolas,

I think what your trying to do is wrong in code.

Try something like this
http://pastebin.com/7AnSxcEh

Give the same height and width to the li and the div. Also add a positioning. so that you can stack up the order.

Answer (score 0):

Well I seem to found the solution for this problem,

```
#reel { width:960px; height:270px;}
#reel li { width:320px; height:327px; z-index:100; position:relative;  }
#reel li img { position:absolute; z-index:98; }
```

Thank you @adrian